# Interchanging differentiation and improper integral

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent continuous random variables with the respective density function $f_X$ and $f_Y$. Then, it is well-known that
$$F_{X+Y}(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F_X(a-y)f_Y(y)dy.$$
Then, the density of $X+Y$ becomes
$$f_{X+Y}(a)=\frac{d}{da}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F_X(a-y)f_Y(y)dy=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_X(a-y)f_Y(y)dy,$$
where the differentiation and the improper integral are interchanged. My question is that can we do this interchange for any continuous random variables having density functions?

As far as I know, since $F_X$ is differentiable in $a$, if the right Riemann integral exists, this interchange is valid. My next question is if the right integral always exist?

Answer (score 1):

Two remarks before:

- for your initial formula to be valid, $X$ and $Y$ should be independent.
- I am considering your integral as a Lebesgue integral rather than a Riemann integral. This makes sense because densities are only uniquely defined outside sets of measure zero.

So your question becomes: is this integral ($g(a)$, say) finite for almost every $a$. The answer is yes. To see this, note first that by [Tonelli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli%27s_theorem):
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(a) da &=  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(a-y)f_Y(y)da \right) dy \\
&=  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_Y(y)\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(a-y)da \right) dy\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_Y(y) dy\\
&=1. 
\end{align*}
This implies that the set $\{a:g(a)=\infty\}$ has Lebesgue measure 0 (otherwise its integral would be infinite).